# Subsonic 3.0 Connection string does not exist error

Tags: subsonic, connection-string

I am new to subsonic. While i am debugging the code,
context.cs is throwing me an error saying that
"The connection string myconnectionstring does not exist".

I am sure the connection string is valid, coz it generated all the fields in a table from the database and populating in the class....

While executing it, its throwing me the error.

Appreciated your help.

Comment: what version of subsonic?  Please post the relevant parts of your .config file and the xxxDB class constructors from your context.cs file (should be in the first 50 lines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please double check that the connection string is in your main app/web.config.
If I remember correctly, for code generation, subsonic looks in the dll's *.config file for a connection string (if you created an extra project for the DAL) but during runtime, the app.config file of the main exe (or for a web project the web.config) need's to have the same connectionstring, too.

Comment: Thank you for u r help. The error was due to i defined the connection string only in the app.config of DAL...once i defined the same connection string in the web.config file...it worked.